# Ionic CSS Components Styling Not Working

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, styling

[Screenshot of original card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmZEF.jpg)

I'm just copying the HTML code of ionic components into my App, but it is not styling like original sample.

```
<ion-view view-title="About us">
  <ion-content padding>
    <h1>About us</h1>
    <ion-card>
       <ion-card-header>
         Header
       </ion-card-header>
       <ion-card-content>
          The British use the term "header", but the American term "head-shot" the English simply refuse to adopt.
       </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>    
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

but it returns me this [Screenshot of result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3BBO.png)

I've checked all css and js is working on page, except ionic components.

Comment: is this ionic 1 or 2?

Comment: it is ionic 1..

Comment: can you paste your code in fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/umairsultan/d7gu74dk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've got the problem. It's the different documentations for ionic v1 and v2 but google only list ionic v2 docs.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components

Thanks to all for your time.

Comment: samething happend to me bro :)